# Laravel websocket - develop mobile chat app using laravel as backend

Tags: laravel, flutter, websocket

I successfully setup `laravel websocket` chat with all the configuration. However, I want to connect it with `flutter` app or mobile app and not sure how to go about it.

The only way I can think of is using `api` route to call `controller` function to post message. but I am not sure how to listen from the app frontend.

How can we listen to the channel without using `echo`, especially I want to develop for mobile app?

I am using `laravel 5.8`, and `flutter` as my frontend.

Comment: I need to implement api for flutter app using laravel. I need to learn how you implemented that part of laravel when mobile app listening for data in an endpoint of laravel. It will be helpful if you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel 
Official example https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets

demo code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'WebSocket Demo';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: title,
        channel: IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://echo.websocket.org'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final WebSocketChannel channel;

  MyHomePage({Key key, @required this.title, @required this.channel})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message'),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: widget.channel.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0),
                  child: Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : ''),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _sendMessage,
        tooltip: 'Send message',
        child: Icon(Icons.send),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  void _sendMessage() {
    if (_controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      widget.channel.sink.add(_controller.text);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

example code of `web_socket_channel`

```
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/status.dart' as status;

main() async {
  var channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://localhost:1234");

  channel.stream.listen((message) {
    channel.sink.add("received!");
    channel.sink.close(status.goingAway);
  });
}
```